# Passing an array using Ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

So my python program is

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes

number = [0,1,2]
testlib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./a.out")


testlib.init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
testlib.init.restype = ctypes.c_double

#create an array of size 3
testlib.init(3)

#Loop to fill the array

#use AccessArray to preform an action on the array
```

And the C part is

```
#include <stdio.h>


double init(int size){
    double points[size];

    return points[0];
}

double fillarray(double value, double location){

    // i need to access 
}

double AccessArray(double value, double location){

    // i need to acess the array that is filled in the previous function
}
```

So what I need to do is to pass an array from the python part to the C function somehow move that array in C to the another function where I will access it in order to process it.

I'm stuck though because I cant figure out a way to move the array in the C part.

can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this (in your C code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

double points[1000];//change 1000 for the maximum size for you
int sz = 0;

double init(int size){
    //verify size <= maximum size for the array
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        points[i] = 1;//change 1 for the init value for you
    }
    sz = size;
    return points[0];
}

double fillarray(double value, double location){
    //first verify 0 < location < sz
    points[(int)location] = value;    
}

double AccessArray(double value, double location){
    //first verify 0 < location < sz
    return points[(int)location];
}
```

This is a very simple solution but if you need to allocate an array with just any size you shoul study the use of [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: this looks good except you mentioned malloc and I had a look but I dont see how I could use that to create the array of a given size.

Comment: `points = malloc(size * sizeof(double));` like in the dstromberg answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$ cat Makefile

go: a.out
        ./c-double

a.out: c.c
        gcc -fpic -shared c.c -o a.out

zareason-dstromberg:~/src/outside-questions/c-double x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 27062 - above cmd done 2013 Fri Dec 27 11:03 AM

$ cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


double *init(int size) {
    double *points;

    points = malloc(size * sizeof(double));

    return points;
}

double fill_array(double *points, int size) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        points[i] = (double) i;
    }

}

double access_array(double *points, int size) {
    // i need to access the array that is filled in the previous function
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d: %f\n", i, points[i]);
    }
}
zareason-dstromberg:~/src/outside-questions/c-double x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 27062 - above cmd done 2013 Fri Dec 27 11:03 AM

$ cat c-double
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import ctypes

testlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./a.out")

testlib.init.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
testlib.init.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

#create an array of size 3
size = 3
double_array = testlib.init(size)

#Loop to fill the array
testlib.fill_array(double_array, size)

#use AccessArray to preform an action on the array
testlib.access_array(double_array, size)
```

Comment: I tried the code you have but I keep getting a segmentation fault, seems to be something to do with the fill and access array parts.

Comment: Set `init.restype = POINTER(c_double)`, but really this is an awkward design if you can avoid it. Have the client allocate the array: `init.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(c_double)]; double_array = (c_double * size)(); init(size, double_array)`. Now `double_array` is managed by a Python, reference counted object. You don't have to worry about `malloc` and `free`. Python  does that for you.

Comment: I tried changing testlib.init.restype = ctypes.c_void_p to testlib.init.restype = POINTER(c_double) but now I get 


  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    testlib.init.restype = POINTER(c_double)
NameError: name 'POINTER' is not defined

Comment: @JohnTracey: I just didn't feel like typing `ctypes` repeatedly. In anything major that gets old *fast*. Type `ctypes` a few hundred times in a module.

Comment: Oh whoops forgot to add that :P, works now thanks for the help.